# Laravel 5.4 и обработка метода POST

Tags: laravel

Сделал простую форму, написал маршрут для файла, на который будет отправляться форма методом POST. В итоге вылезает ошибка. В чем может быть дело? Пробовал POST менять на GET - тогда работает.
P.S. Код представил скринами, так как не получилось показать его именно "как код".
[image: Форма]

[image: route]

[image: exp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отсутствует защищенный token. Поставьте

```
{{csrf_field()}}
```

или

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"
```

Замените

```
<form action="/comments" method="post">
```

на

```
<form action="{{Route("comments")}}" method="post">
```

В роуте

```
Route::post("comments", funciton(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){

pritn_r($request);//$request то есть $_POST, $_POST['title'] это $request['title];

})->name("comments"); // у каждого роута должно быть имя
```

Comment: Добавил строку <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"> в форму - не помогает.     А куда добавлять только {{csrf_field()}}   ?

Comment: Внутри тега форм. {{csrf_field()}} и <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" одно и тоже . {{csrf_field()}} укороченный

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing смотрите здесь

Comment: Что то не помогает. Но сделал вот так:    Вы можете отключить проверку CSRF-токена определенного маршрута добавив его (маршрут) в поле $except в VerifyCsrfToken middleware: